# How to display nav-items in one row for all device in bootstrap?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

https://jsfiddle.net/hx1zm6wh/5/

I want to show in all device as like web.its fine for medium device but not same for mobile and tablet.
please suggest me...

```
<header id="page-header">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
    <nav >
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">service</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">career</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</header>
```

Here is my css code

```
#page-header{
    background-color:grey;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.nav-pills > li > a {
    color: #000 !important;
    direction: inline-block;
}
.nav-pills > li > a.active {
    background-color: #000;
}
.nav-pills > li.active >a{
    color: #fff !important;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Flexbox, and modify your font sizes, but getting all that text to fit on a 320px screen on one line is a bad idea and likely bad UX

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://jsfiddle.net/hx1zm6wh/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all "col-xs-6" is the class for extra small devices that's why you need to add this class "col-xs-12 col-sm-6" so that you can get full width in mobile devices. Refer this image to understand.[image]

Now you want to display nav items in one row for all devices, For that you need to add media query for custom css. Refer the snippet.

```css
#page-header{
    background-color:grey;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.nav-pills > li > a {
    color: #000 !important;
    direction: inline-block;
}
.nav-pills > li > a.active {
    background-color: #000;
}
.nav-pills > li.active >a{
    color: #fff !important;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 480px){ 
  .nav>li>a{
    padding: 5px 5px;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<header id="page-header">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
    <nav >
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">service</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">career</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

To get them all one one line, you can do something like this (modified your current code)

```
.nav-pills {
  display: flex;
}
.nav-pills > li {
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.nav-pills > li > a {
    color: #000 !important;
}
```

But I wouldn't suggest this approach for mobiles.